# Polymer 1.0 Iron-form Post error 404 not found

Tags: php, forms, post, polymer

Working with Polymer 1.0, I try to implement the iron-form element, when I use the method "GET" it's working, but when I try to make a "POST" about the same file on the same path error occurs 404 not found.

My custom element (contact-form):

```
<dom-module id="contact-form">
<template>
<div class="horizontal center-center layout">        
  <link rel="import" href="add.php">     
   <div>     
        <div class="horizontal-saction>    
         <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" content-type="application/json" action="add.php"> 
           <paper-input name="name" label="Name" requiered></paper-input>
            <br><br> 
           <paper-button raised onclick="sumitForm()">Submit</paper-button> 
         </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>      
</template>
<script>
 function submitForm(){
  document.getElementById('form').submit();
 }
 Polymer({
          is:'contact-form', 
         });
```

My add.php contains:

```
<?php  
 var_dump($_POST['name']);
?>
```

The file path add.php is elements/contact-form/add.php and 404 not found, when I "POST", occurs on the same path http: //localhost:5000/elements/contact-form/add.php. I do not understand because it happens. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me your server configuration must be doing something different with GET and PUT requests.  YOu make no mention of what server you have and how its configured, but first check in dev tools if you have a chrome browser and watch the traffic to and from the server.

EDIT - further update on some thought in this
Submitting the form

`<paper-button id="submit" >Submit</paper-button>`

Then in your Polymer object

`listeners: {'submit.tap':'_submitlogon'},
_submitLogon: function() {
   this.$.form.submit();
}`

SECOND EDIT.

If you are using gulp serve, then it is using its own web server.  This has no ability to run any php code.  So probably what is coming back is the raw text of php source code. If its stored in a place where the server can find it.   I am wondering how the ajax request is being handled - since it is expecting (specifically in POST mode, so I don't understand how GET worked) a JSON formatted response.  Obviously the source of your PHP isn't json, so it won't recognise the format and error out.

Comment: I use gulp serve, in windows, installing according to the instructions on the page, using Polymer Sarter kit. I visualized in Chrome traffic and error occurs is: "Error: The request failed with status code: 404 at iron-request <anonymous> (http: // localhost: 50 ...}". I searched the gulpfile.js but I can not find the method setup. Can you tell me how to configure it? Thanks

Comment: iron request is your ajax call.  Is the code you posted above actually your code because there a couple of spelling errors in it, so I am surprised it ever worked.  Note also the way you are submitting the form is not the recommended way.

Comment: gulp serve is a task in the gulpfile.  It uses browserSync with an object in the call which has a section server.routes.

Comment: I deploy to app engine and the error no occurs. Thank you.